# Feynman's corrective term in his approach to the Onsager Problem

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, partition-function

I am studying Feynman's book: 'Statistical Mechanics: A set of lectures' and his approach to the Onsager problem(Section 5.4). In the subsection 'Method of Calculating partition Function', Feynman introduces the seemingly arbitrary choice of a corrective term to the partition function:

$Q' = e^{Nq} - 2T \frac{dq}{dT}$

where $- 2T \frac{dq}{dT}$ would be the corrective term.

Apparently, the 2 $q$'s in $Q'$ are different as well, but Feynman does not explain this nor does he justify its appearance.

Where does the term arise from or is there some other source which explains/justifies this choice of corrective term?